# Son dificiles las relaciones con TypeORM?

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript

tengo un problema con TypeORM y es que no hay tanta documentacion en TypeORM sobre relaciones entre entidades. Necesito hacer OneToMany y ManyToMany y no puedo porque se me complica con el ORM, se pueden hacer en este ORM o me conviene hacerlas en SQL directamente? Si alguien sabe y me ayuda gracias. Esta es mi Entity del User

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
  
    @Column()
    firstname: string;
  
    @Column()
    lastname: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @Column({unique: true})
    email: string;

    @Column({unique: true})
    cuil: string;

    @Column()
    adress: string;

    @Column({default: "USER_ROLE"})
    role: string;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    createdAt: Date;
  
    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updatedAt: Date;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Si se pueden configurar, si lees la documentación te enteras como llevarlo a cabo: https://typeorm.io/relations